# Prevent HTML Radio Button Selects on Arrow Key using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If someone can help me in here to modify the existing behavior of radio buttons as per below.

We need this for accessibility.

```
TAB> Moves to the next radio button group within the same row or the next row.

Up> Moves to the previous radio button within the current group if available.

Down> Moves to the next radio button within the current group if available.

Left> Moves to the previous radio button within the current group if available.

Right> Moves to the next radio button within the current group if available.
```

Comment: have you tried anything from your side?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this my accessing the key event of keyboard.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').keydown(function(e)
{
    var arrowKeys = [37, 38, 39, 40];
    if (arrowKeys.indexOf(e.which) !== -1)
    {

        if (e.which == 38)
        {
           //jquery code to move right or left 
// set the element you want to focus on
        }
        else if (e.which == 40)
        {
     //jquery code to move top or down
// set the element you want to focus on
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using this code but the problem is the radio buttons are getting selected. I would need radio button should not be selected and when press space bar key radio button should be selected

Comment: you can use $(this).blur() to blur from the current radio. And if you want to select by spacebar use  if (e.keyCode == 32){$(this).attr('checked',true);   }

Comment: var keyPressed = null;
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function(event) {
    if (keyPressed && keyPressed > 36 && keyPressed < 41) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    keyPressed = e.which;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    keyPressed = null;
});